# gitlab runner pod doesn't have docker.sock

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Recently i have deployed gitlab runner with helm in my kubernetes. The probelm is that i have created a docker image based on docker:dind which has some packages for maven and when gitlab runs `runner` pod based on my image, the pod doesn't have the `docker.sock`. I don't know where is the problem ?
I have used the below image for runners:

```
image: <my private-registry>/dind-java17-new:17
```

and here is my runner config in `values.yml` gitlab runner :

```
runners:
  # runner configuration, where the multi line strings is evaluated as
  # template so you can specify helm values inside of it.
  #
  # tpl: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function
  # runner configuration: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      executor = "kubernetes"
    [runners.kubernetes]
      privileged = true
      helper_image = "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-782e15da"
```

I have tried the below solution in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` but it didn't work :

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
services:
  - name: <my private-registry>/dind-java17-new:17
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And i got this error :

```
error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/version": dial tcp: lookup docker on 169.254.25.10:53: server misbehaving
```

Happy to hear any solutions!

Comment: It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/74958689/14046582

Comment: It didn't help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem!. Actaully when you wanna use `docker:dind` in gitlab-runner kubernetes executor, the `docker:dind` image has an entrypoint for running `docker.sock` named `dockerd-entrypoint.sh` and it will run as `ENTRYPOINT` in your container but the problem is gitlab-runner build container will override the entrypoint of the `docker:dind` image. So for passing away this problem i ran the `dockerd-entrypoint.sh` manually in `before_script` section in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file so my container contains `docker.sock`.